# Tags merge will be appropriate: [adt] and [eclipse-adt] and [adt-bundle]

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

The [eclipse-adt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-adt) and [adt-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adt-bundle) tags are duplicates of a significantly more popular [adt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adt), and should be merged with the latter if possible.

Comment: And here I immediately thought "Abstract Data Types"...

Comment: @Deduplicator: all three tags may very soon become obsolete and I won't protest recycling one for something cool like abstract data types

Comment: There is also [tag:algebraic-data-types]

Comment: There is a pending synonym here, please vote -- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adt/synonyms